# Installing LockBox 3 to Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, lockbox-3

I am trying to install Lockbox 3.5 to Delphi 7. I have come to the point where it should compile, but I am having some trouble with `TBytes`. 
Delphi sees `TBytes` as an `Undeclared identifier`.

I am a student in my first year and don't know exactly how to fix this problem.

```
function SelfTest_Key: TBytes;
```

This script is found under uTPLb_BlockCipher.

```
function Stream_to_Base64(ASource: TStream; const ATransform: TBytes = nil) : TBytes;
```

This script is found under uTPLb_StreamUtils

I would really appreciate any input.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Please take your time to read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What makes you think Delphi 7 is supported?

Comment: The lockbox readme files declares Delphi 7 as supported.

Comment: 3.5 : `Removed support for all other compilers (other than XE6 and D2010)` 3.6 : `Support for all compilers from Delphi 7 and up` [ref:](http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/HomePage)

Comment: Where can I get hold of 3.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the project [release history](http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/ReleaseHistory):

> Version 3.5.0
>
> - Removed support for all other compilers (other than XE6 and D2010). The return of support for other compilers will be coming soon.
> - ...

From the project [website](http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/HomePage):

> With 3.5.0 as the baseline, the 3.6.0 version delivers:
>
> - Support for all compilers from Delphi 7 and up (although only package heads for D2010 and XE6 written at the moment).
> - ...

The above page contains a link to the [download area](http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/Grok+TurboPower+LockBox) which says:

> **LTS - the Long Term Support release**
>
> This is the "Long Term Support" (LTS) version. This release is
>   typically used for Enterprise deployments or other users that do not
>   want frequent major upgrades .
>
> The current LTS version is 3.5.0 . The LTS was set to this version on
>   11-Jul-2014. The LTS can be downloaded from SourceForge here
>   https://tplockbox.googlecode.com/svn/tags/LB%203.5.0.0%2011-Jul-2014.
>
> **STABLE - the current stable release**
>
> Recommended to users who want a stable high quality product, and
>   timely access to enhancements and defect corrections.
>
> The current STABLE version is 3.6.0 . The STABLE was set to this
>   version on 11-Nov-2014. The STABLE can be downloaded from SourceForge
>   here
>   https://tplockbox.googlecode.com/svn/tags/LB%203.6.0.0%2010-Nov-2014/.

So, it would appear that you need to download version 3.6.0.

Please take time to read the documentation at the pages linked above.